# Visitor IP banning for 24 hours after clicking certain button

Tags: php, html, mysql

I know this can be done in mysql  but I want the IP to be stored in php or a text file and its kinda hard for me because I do not quite understand it.

$SESSION is used to log but how can it be stored and banned for 24 hours after a html button is clicked.
Many thanks

Comment: You will need to save the date & time of the request along with the IP somewhere.

Comment: @atymic thats where im stuck, how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick.

We write the visitors IP and the time that the ban expires to a text file. We then load this and check if they are in that file, and still banned.

```php
function ban()
{
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    file_put_contents(
        'bans.txt',
        sprintf("%s;%s\n", $ip, (new DateTime())->add(new DateInterval('PT24H'))->getTimestamp()),
        FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

}

function checkBan()
{
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $bans = file('bans.txt');

    foreach ($bans as $ban) {
        $banExpiry = (int) explode(';', $ban)[1];

        if ($banExpiry < time()) {
            continue;
        }

        $bannedIp = explode(';', $ban)[0];

        if ($bannedIp === $ip) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, do I have to put it in index.php? Or any necessary changes?

Comment: You can put the functions above wherever, and then call them in your code.